# How do I give a Kivy BoxLayout a Background using Python?

Tags: python, background, widget, kivy

Also interested in other non-Button widgets as well, like a GridLayout or Label. Mostly I'm interested in BorderImages, but an answer that talks about regular Images would be welcome, of course.

I've found many examples using Builder and KV files, but I'm interested in doing it purely in Python. Here's what I'm trying now:

```
    ab = BoxLayout(orientation='horizontal',
                   height=self.widgetHeight,
                   size_hint_y=None)
    with ab.canvas.before:
        BorderImage(
            width=self.width,
            height=self.widgetHeight,
            pos=(0,0),
            border=(15, 15, 15, 15),
            source='button-up.png')
```

This does not work, but neither does it give an error.

EDIT: After getting Inclement, and Totem's comments, and thank you so much for those documents, but I'm afraid I've already seen those documents. I will share a bit more detail on what I'm doing when I follow those docs:

```
def redrawAB(self,*args,**kwargs):
    self.bg_rect.size = self.size
    self.bg_rect.pos = self.pos
def myActionBar(self):
    ab = BoxLayout(orientation='horizontal', 
        height=self.widgetHeight,
        size_hint_y=None)
    with ab.canvas:
        ab.bg_rect = BorderImage(width=self.width,
            height=self.widgetHeight,
            pos=(0,0), border=(15, 15, 15, 15),
            source='button.png')
    ab.bind(pos=self.redrawAB, size=self.redrawAB)
    return ab
```

Though I don't think this is a relevant detail, elsewhere in the code, we do:

```
 widget.add_widget(self.myActionBar())
```

With the above, the app will crash on start with this error:

```
  AttributeError: 'InterfaceManager' object has no attribute 'bg_rect'
```

The "InterfaceManager" is the parent widget of these things. So I think somehow I need to let the `redrawAB()` know about the `ab.bg_rect` object, and I'm not sure how to get `ab.bind()` to pass the reference to the object?

Here is another attempt that didn't work. I get no errors, but I get no usable object with interface widgets (I just get a blank area on the screen where it should go):

```
class MyActionBar(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(BoxLayout, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.height=kwargs['height']
        self.orientation='horizontal'
        self.size_hint_y=None

        with self.canvas:
            self.bg_rect = BorderImage(border=(15, 15, 15, 15), source='button.png')
        self.bind(pos=self.redrawAB, size=self.redrawAB)

    def redrawAB(self,*args,**kwargs):
        self.bg_rect.size = self.size
        self.bg_rect.pos = self.pos

#...in another class comes the following...

    parent_boxlayout.add_widget(MyActionBar(height=128))
```

Comment: http://inclem.net/2014/10/10/kivy/kivy_update_instructions/

Comment: http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.widget.html#basic-drawing

Comment: inclement: were you referring to this portion of your post? "We don’t need to manually set up the binding because kv automatically detects that we referred to properties of the parent widget and creates it automatically - something that isn’t really possible in Python." Sounds like you're saying this isn't possible using Python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am answering my own question, since I've found a work-around.

The first is to create an AnchorLayout with a background image and BoxLayout one after the other, like so:

```
a = AnchorLayout(anchor_x='center', anchor_y='center')
i = Image(source='thing.png')
a.add_widget(i)
b = BoxLayout(orientation='horizontal')
a.add_widget(b)
```

The more traditional, and more painful method: Instead of putting a background on a BoxLayout (the goal being to put other widgets in front of it), just break up the image into chunks and put each chunk into the BoxLayout in Buttons (or Images, if you don't need Button behaviour), like so:

```
    ab = BoxLayout(orientation='horizontal', height=self.widgetHeight, size_hint_y=None)
    bt = Button(background_normal='left.png', size_hint_x=None, width=self.widgetHeight)
    ab.add_widget(bt)
    bt = Button(background_normal='right.png',text='Second',border=(10,10,10,10))
    ab.add_widget(bt)
```